# PowerShell to use WinSCP .NET assembly with secure credentials

Tags: powershell, credentials, winscp, winscp-net

I'm trying to use WinSCP .NET assembly with secure credential, when the password secured in external file.

```powershell
# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "D:\WinSCPnet.dll"

# Setup session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions
$sessionOptions.Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp

# Env
$sessionOptions.HostName = "blabla.com"
$sessionOptions.UserName = "UUUU"
#$sessionOptions.Password = "PPPP"
$sessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint = "XXXXXXXXX"
$remotePath = "/home/UUUU/"
```

With hard coded password its working. If I would like to use securestring for the password, how should I do that?

I tried:

```powershell
read-host -assecurestring | convertfrom-securestring | out-file D:\securestring.txt
```

To keep the secure password in a file. Then, in my script, I get it back:

```powershell
$sessionOptions.Password = get-Content D:\securestring.txt | convertto-securestring

$Cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $sessionOptions.UserName, $sessionOptions.Password}
```

But it's not working...

Answer (score 4):

Since WinSCP 5.7, the assembly accepts the `SecureString` using the `SessionOptions.SecurePassword`.

See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions

Thanks for inspiring [this improvement](https://winscp.net/tracker/1230).

While the assembly keeps the password encrypted in memory, it still needs to decrypt it eventually. Improvements to limit internal copies of the decrypted password are pending.

Answer (score 3):

As [@Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26202643/1630171) pointed out, the WinSCP .Net assembly doesn't accept secure strings or credential objects. You need to pass the password as a plaintext string. You can store the [secure string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6982236/1630171) in a file, though:

```powershell
Read-Host 'Enter password' -AsSecureString |
  ConvertFrom-SecureString |
  Out-File 'C:\password.txt'
```

and use a `PSCredential` object to retrieve the decrypted password from the secure string after you read it from the file:

```powershell
$un   = 'username'
$pw   = Get-Content 'C:\password.txt' | ConvertTo-SecureString
$cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential $un, $pw

try {
  Add-Type -Path 'WinSCPnet.dll'

  $opt = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions
  $opt.Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
  $opt.HostName = 'example.org'
  $opt.UserName = $cred.UserName
  $opt.Password = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password
  $opt.SshHostKeyFingerprint = 'ssh-rsa 2048 ...'

  $sftp = New-Object WinSCP.Session

  $sftp.Open($opt)
  ...
} catch {
  ...
} finally {
  if ($sftp) { $sftp.Dispose() }
}
```

WinSCP sample code taken from the [documentation](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell#example).

Note, however, that the password must be saved by the same user who is running the SFTP PowerShell script, because the encryption key is derived from that user's password.

Comment: WinSCP .NET assembly already supports `SecureString`, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26279430/850848).

Comment: It didn't at the point when I was writing my answer, before you added `SecureString` support. ;) Thank you very much for your work, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

According to [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions) the password property just supports a string. So trying to pass a secure string will not work. If you *really* want to store the password in a file, you could attempt to store it as the secure string but that is a [really bad idea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) in general since it can be unsecured just as easily (Also not sure if it is possible). I recommend the following option.

```
# Only stored in memory which is safer.
$sessionOptions.Password = read-host
```

If you have your heart set on something else you could try this. Just know for previous reasons I **do not** condone this. Also i have to see if it even works because it looks like you cant output `securestring` to file.

```
read-host | out-file D:\securestring.txt
$sessionOptions.Password = get-Content D:\securestring.txt
```

Ansgar's explains what I didn't know was possible. You can stored the secure string in a file and use it elsewhere.

Comment: WinSCP .NET assembly already supports `SecureString`, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26279430/850848).